# Ubuntu server 14.04.1 won't boot

Tags: installation

I installed Ubuntu server 14.04.1 on an old Toshiba Satellite A665-S5170. I installed it from a USB drive.  Setup and everything went fine but now I can't boot into Ubuntu server without the USB in. If I take it out it says it failed to boot from the hdd.

Comment: Seems that you have installed a  "Live-USB Ubuntu". I would say : perform a full install to HDD instead

Comment: @user2196728 I downloaded Ubuntu server from the Ubuntu website then used pendrive linux's universal USB installer to load the iso onto a USB and then booted from it. Is that not the correct way?

Comment: If you want to install Ubuntu on your HDD it is not the correct way. If you want to install Ubuntu on your HDD still using an USB [have a look here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Comment: Great ! Will write an answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have installed a "Live-USB Ubuntu".

To boot Ubuntu from HDD you have to perform an install to HDD.

If you still want to use your USB stick to store the ISO and install from it, then you will have to follow these steps :

1. Acquire the correct Ubuntu installation files ('the ISO')
2. Put Ubuntu onto your USB flash drive
3. Configure your computer to boot from USB flash drive and boot from
   it
4. Install Ubuntu to your internal drive (hard disk drive or solid
   state drive).

[You will find further infos and full procedure here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)